# Buscar datos no asociados a ninguno en una relacion many to many

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo varias tablas relacionadas entre si mediante la relación many to many (muchos a muchos). Me gustaría saber como puedo acceder a los datos que no han sido asociado a otros. Por ejemplo: quiero sacar cuales clientes no están asociados a un usuario.

Puedo revisar cuales clientes si tienen un usuario de esta forma: $cliente->users, pero lo contrario no se como hacerlo.

Esta es mi consulta.

```
public function show($operador){

    $operador = Operador::findOrFail($operador);
    $clientesAsociados = $operador->clientes()->paginate(8);
    
    return view('admin.operador.show', [
        'operador' => $operador,
        'clientesAsociados' => $clientesAsociados,
        
    ]);

    
}
```

Comment: Listo @BetaM, De esa forma accedo a los clientes que tienen un operador asociado, me gustaría saber como consultar los clientes que no tienen ningún operador asociado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clase **`BelongsToMany`** se vale de la clase *builder de Eloquent* y esta a su vez **usa** un trait llamado: **QueriesRelationships**.

Lo anterior te lo comento por que dicho *trait* posee de entre varios un método que nos ayudará a *obtener* en este caso: los modelos de clientes basándonos en la ausencia de  relación con los operadores; el cual es [**`doesntHave`**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence)

Entonces puedes componer tu consulta de esta forma:

```
$clientesSinOperadores = Cliente::doesntHave('operadores')->get();
```

Lo anterior te daría una colección de todos los clientes que no tienen al menos un operador relacionado.

Por el contrario si quieres obtener solo un objeto de cliente que no tiene operadores relacionados, lo puedes hacer encadenando al final de la query el método `findOrFail()` así:

```
$clienteSinOperadores = Cliente::doesntHave('operadores')->findOrFail($idCliente);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias nuevamente. Me sirvió tu respuesta.